# SessionNotCreatedError: session not created Error in Protractor automation

Tags: javascript, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I have an angular app which I am trying to run Protractor automation test on it. But when I am trying to run the automation test I am getting the following error.
I have Chrome browser 86 and placed the chrome 86 chromedriver.exe under the node_moules/protractor/selenium/.But still I am getting the following error.

Dont know where to set the path to ask protractor to pickup chrome86 driver. Any help appreciated.

```
Running "shell:protractor_install" (shell) task
selenium standalone is up to date.
Updating chromedriver to version 83.0.4103.61
downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.61/chromedriver_win32.zip...
Ignoring SSL certificate
>> Error: Got error Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.61/chromedriver_win32.zip

Running "protractor:test" (protractor) task
[16:20:43] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:20:43] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49455/devtools/browser/799cea95-40ad-4ed5-84c0-dfb2aaa13de6

C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27
    super(opt_error);
    ^
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83
  (Driver info: chromedriver=83.0.4103.14 (be04594a2b8411758b860104bc0a1033417178be-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#119}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27:5)
    at SessionNotCreatedError (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:296:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:580:13)
    at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:64:13
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2773:21)
    at asyncRun (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2652:27)
    at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at acquireSession (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:62:22)
    at Function.createSession (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:295:12)
    at Driver (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:778:38)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:65:26)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:182:43)
    at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:255:30
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
[16:20:52] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
>> C:\Users\502622018\dmro-workspace\Workscope-E2E-Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\error.js:27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it automatically without having to download every new version of chromedriver is to let the webdriver-manager package do its job.

```
node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
protractor <your_configuration_js>
```

Note: See how webdriver-manager is called above, it uses the local version inside your project npm modules (not the global one). It syncs very well the settings below.

Enabling this key is a must if you used the steps above on your **protractor configuration** . This doesn't need to use/execute `webdriver-manager start` everytime you start your test.

```
directConnect: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue when I changed the protractor/config.json to point to the latest chromedriver for 86

```
{
  "webdriverVersions": {
    "selenium": "2.52.0",
    "chromedriver": "86.0.4240.22",
    "iedriver": "2.52.0"
  }
}
```

Then downloaded the file manually and placed it in the protractor/selenium and changed the extension to chromedriver_86.0.4240.22.exe